# How to integrate microsoft project 2007 with sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, project-server

I want to develop a report in microsoft sharepoint 2007 which can connect to microsoft project 2007 server , How can I start my work ?  Anyone can recommend me some information (book, url, blog etc)

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Project Server 2007 is built on top of SharePoint 2007. When developing for Microsoft Project Server 2007, you have access to all of the APIs provided by SharePoint...all you have to do is use them.

If you're new to developing for SharePoint 2007, I would suggest starting out at the MSDN Library for SharePoint and reading as much as you can:

[Microsoft SharePoint Products and Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb931739.aspx)

Just be sure to read the articles/posts for SharePoint 2007 rather than 2010.

Comment: So actually, if I want to get the data within project server 2007, what api should I use ?  as I am not familiar with sharepoint, can u point me the right direction for my research ? For example recommend a book or blog ?  Thanks !

Comment: Heres the link for the Project Server 2007 SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=2672F6F9-7028-4B30-99A2-18CB1EED1ABE&displaylang=en